# rewrite URL in Wordpress using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

Hi I need to rewrite URL in Wordpress.
I have a website where pages are created thanks to data loaded from JSON files.
These data allow me to create custom links that send the parameters via the URL.

I set the permalinks with /% postname% /

Example:
https://example.com/postname/?lid=16036&name=John&st=2019-2020

I need to transform in
https://example.com/16036/John/2019-2020.html

To do that the rule is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /postname/?lid=$1&name=$2&st=$3 [L]
```

Added in htaccess but nothing changes

I use a plugin "Admin Tools for Wordpress" that allow me to change htaccess

The support says:
I don't think that you are on the right path. It sounds like you're trying to convert

https://example.com/postname/?lid=16036&name=John&st=2019-2020

to

https://example.com/16036/John/2019-2020.html

in the HTML output of the page.

Apache Rewrite cannot do that. And before you ask, no, Admin Tools has nothing to help you with that nor can it possibly have such a feature due to the way WordPress pages are generated (there is no document buffer like there is in Joomla)

Can anyone tell me if there is any way to do this?

Comment: "Apache Rewrite cannot do that." - I think the "problem" is WordPress, not Apache. Whilst you can rewrite the URL using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. WP internally looks at the REQUEST_URI when routing the request and this does not change when the URL is rewritten using Apache. You need to do this a WP specific way in WP itself.

Comment: Apache’s mod_rewrite handles one _direction_ of this - rewriting the incoming request for the “pretty” URL, into the variant with parameters. It does not handle the creation of those pretty URLs in the first place - if you want any of the links on your page to point to `/16036/John/2019-2020.html`, then you need to see to it that your system creates the according HTML code to begin with. That’s what the support was trying to tell you here.